# Suppose $(A \cap C) \subset (B \cap C)$ and $(A \cup C) \subset (B \cup C).$ Prove that $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Please help. I'm trying along the lines of proof by cases but I'm really stuck.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ be an element of $A$. We have to show that $x$ is in $B$.

One of two things can happen: either $x$ is in $C$ or $x$ is not in $C$.

Suppose $x$ is in $C$. Then, $x$ is in $A \cap C$ (it is already in $A$), so by what we are given, $x$ is in $B\cap C$. This means that $x$ is in $B$.

Suppose that $x$ is not in $C$. Then, $x$ is in $A \cup C$ (it is already in $A$, so membership in $C$ does not matter), so by what we are given, $x$ is in $B \cup C$. This means that $x$ is in $B$ or that $x$ is in $C$, but we already know it is not in $C$, hence $x$ must be in $B$.

Either way, $x$ is in $B$, so $A$ is a subset  of $B$.